# ffmpeg sRGB jpgs to rec709 mov

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert an sRGB jpeg sequence into a rec709 DnX Quicktime... but struggle to get the colormatrix right.

```
ffmpeg -y -f image2 -start_number 1 -framerate 24 -i input.%04d.jpg -c:v dnxhd -vf "scale=1920:1080,fps=24,format=yuv422p10,colorspace=all=bt709:itrc=srgb" -b:v 175M -c:a pcm_s16le output.mov
```

My understanding is this should set everything to rec709, but override the input response curve (itrc=srgb), but this fails with

```
Unsupported input primaries 2 (unknown)
Error while filtering: Invalid argument
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

I haven't been able to come up with any combination of flags that doesn't trough an error and produces the right colors.

Some docs here: [ffmpeg filters trc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#trc)

Any help much appreciated!

**Edit:**
Full log:

```
$ ffmpeg -y -f image2 -start_number 1 -framerate 24 -i input.%04d.jpg -c:v dnxhd -vf "scale=1920:1080,fps=24,format=yuv422p10,colorspace=all=bt709:itrc=srgb" -b:v 175M -c:a pcm_s16le output.mov
ffmpeg version 4.3.1-2020-11-08-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --en
able-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-li
bmfx --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, image2, from 'input.%04d.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.13, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080 [SAR 1200:1200 DAR 16:9], 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> dnxhd (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0000026ac0f81600] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, mov, to 'output.mov':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: dnxhd (DNXHD) (AVdn / 0x6E645641), yuv422p10le, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-1024, 175000 kb/s, 24 fps, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 dnxhd
[Parsed_colorspace_3 @ 0000026ac0f7e080] Unsupported input primaries 2 (unknown)
Error while filtering: Invalid argument
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: I've edited the question with the full log